# Can I create a new Account for ELL?

Tags: discussion

I have been suspended from ELL for voting irregularities.

The suspension period ends on Dec 22 at 18:45. I am unable to ask questions, answer questions and chat. So, can I create a new account for ELL and ask questions,  answer questions, and chat there in ELL? I will then merge two account to together.

Comment: Why downvotes in my question?

Comment: downvotes work differently on meta. It means people disagree. As for the suspension - the second L is for *learning* Cheating is bad mkay? You should treat this as a learning experience, helping you to be a better person.

Comment: What would be the point in a suspension if it was ok to simply use a new account?

Answer (score 29):

You've been suspended.  That applies to *you*, not just to a particular account.  Creating another account in order to keep participating on the site is likely to lead to an even longer suspension.  Don't do that; just wait it out.  There are 160+ sites on the network; if you've learned your lesson, find someplace else to hang out until it's over.  And if you haven't learned your lesson, take the time to study the information the moderators provided you so you don't get in trouble again.

Oh, and **especially** if you were suspended for voting irregularities, creating a sockpuppet account would be really, truly the wrong way to respond.  Think about how that looks.

The general rule on Stack Exchange is that you are allowed to have more than one account **if you don't use them to do something you couldn't do with one account**.  That is, you can't use your multiple accounts to vote for each other (= voting for yourself), or double-vote on other posts, or collect the rep for answering your own questions... or evade a suspension. Don't do it.

Comment: I didn't know that before that It's not allowed to vote for own question or answer. When I knew about it, I was suspended. So, First of All the Modarators should have warned me about this issue so that I Would have Removed My second Account or Revoted to Fix the voting irregularities. But, They didn't tell me about it first and suspended me without even Informing me about the suspension.

Comment: I don't know what happened on ELL (that's between you & them), but are you saying that it didn't occur to you that voting for yourself might be a problem? If that's ok, why stop at 2 accounts -- make 50 and give yourself tons of rep, right? What could be wrong with that? No, it's not spelled out explicitly in the help center (though maybe it's in the stuff you see/click through upon creating an account; can't remember), but lots of things aren't spelled out explicitly & yet are still wrong. But the good news is that after your suspension ends, if you behave you'll be fine -- no hard feelings.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I will obey your advice.

Answer (score 12):

## No

What would be the purpose of the suspension if you could just make a new account to circumvent it?

Don't create multiple accounts to attempt to circumvent the restrictions placed on your account, such accounts are normally merged or banned, possibly increasing the restrictions placed on your account.